# Library Settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, app-config

1. I have a library project that accesses the database configured in app.config
2. I have a web project that accesses the database configured in web.config

Both are working properly

Now I want to use the library from the web project.
In Visual Studio works fine.
In production server the web project access the database but the library not is capable of accessing the database from the project web.

The ConnectionString in app.config and web.config are identical.
In production server should not take the web.config settings?

Thanks and sorry for my English

**EDIT**

web.config and app.config connectionStrings

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="IntranetConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Intranet;Integrated Security=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
    <add name="Database.Properties.Settings.IntranetConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Intranet;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: but what's the error that your getting? could you show us the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try copying local the reference of the libraries, to do this, `right-click` the reference in your project, then, in the properties, set `True` to `Copy Local`, now you will have the libraries locally in your server.

This should work if the problem is related to the references of the libraries, it won't help if it's a `web.config/app.config` problem

Comment: The problem not is references, is configuration.

---
Spanish:
El problema no es de referencias, es de configuración.

Comment: Could you post the .config files?

Comment: ....
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="IntranetConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Intranet;Integrated Security=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Database.Properties.Settings.IntranetConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Intranet;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
.....

Comment: edit your question, and update your app.config in the question, not here

Answer (score 0):

The DLL generally takes the app.config of the host application that is calling it and not its own config. Is there some meat here?

Comment: When you publish it the config goes into [app_name].exe.config and not app.config, is that what's wrong?

Comment: It is a web project (not exe). When I publish web.config is correct. The database access  works fine from within the application but not from the DLL. The DLL is not taking web.config settings!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

In the DLL create a class to access the DataTable with a constructor that receives the ConnectionString

```
public TestBLL(String ConnectionString)
{
    TestTableAdapter ta = new TestTableAdapter();
    ta.Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
}
```

In the Web project:

```
String cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IntranetConnectionString"].ToString();
TestBLL taBLL = new TestBLL(cs);
```

In taBLL have the methods to access each Query